# On a Bernoulli or Beta likelihood, why is the uniform prior sometimes referred to as $p^{-1}(1-p)^{-1}$?

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

I usually think of a uniform prior on a Bernoulli or Beta likelihood when trying to find a posterior as being $Beta(1,1) \sim U(0,1) \propto p^0(1-p)^0 = 1$. However, recently in a lot of literature I see that they refer to a uniform prior as being: $p^{-1}(1-p)^{-1}$. I don't really get why this is called a uniform prior instead. Would anyone have any insight? Thanks!

Comment: Please support your claim that this is called a uniform prior. on $p$ "in a lot of literature" - who says it, where? If it happens a lot a few examples shouldn't be hard to give.  I expect that the places where you think you see this they're saying something other than what you think they are saying (it may be that the word "uniform" is mentioned in respect of a prior on something other than $p$ itself, for example)

Comment: Can you provide the references in the "literature" where the Haldane prior is called uniform? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to see links to such references calling$$\pi(p)\propto p^{-1}(1-p)^{-1}$$a "uniform" prior..! This is called the *Haldane prior* in the Bayesian literature, named after [the geneticist J.B.S. Haldane (1892-1964)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._B._S._Haldane).

It is not a recommended prior in that it does not return a proper posterior for all values of the observation $x\sim\mathcal{B}(n,p)$, hence "depends" on the observation since it can only be used when $x\ne 0,n$.

Another traditional and non-uniform prior is Jeffreys' prior$$\pi^J(p)\propto p^{-1/2}(1-p)^{-1/2}$$which is a $\mathcal{B}e(1/2,1/2)$ (proper) distribution and hence the posterior distribution $\pi(p|x)$ is defined for all values of the observation $x\sim\mathcal{B}(n,p)$.